# How do I make a Stream `max` early-terminate?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm writing against OpenJDK 16 and trying to make good use of streams. I have a case that calls for a hybrid of `Stream.max`, getting the element for which this comparator:

```
    public static final Comparator<Solution> byMatched =
        Comparator.comparing(sol -> sol.pairs.size());
```

indicates the largest `pairs` collection; but also I need to early-terminate if this `size()` reaches a known upper limit. About the closest I think I can get with built-ins is

```
    public Solution best() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(this, true)
            .takeWhile(
                solution -> solution.pairs().size() < problem.animals().size()
            )
            .max(Solution.byMatched)
            .get();
    }
```

where `this` implements `Spliterator<Solution>`. This approach is not correct because, whereas it does early-terminate, the first solution seen that reaches the maximum problem size is discarded by `takeWhile`.

Is there a built-in stream approach that applies a `max`, but stops at (and includes the first value for!) a given predicate becoming `true`?

Comment: Just to be clear, your stream is sorted by size?

Comment: @Sweeper No, it is effectively unordered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a stateful predicate that returns true until after the first input that exceeds the threshold has been encountered.

Something like this:

```
class BoundedPredicate<T, V extends Comparable<V>> implements Predicate<T> {
    private V boundary; //the boundary
    private Function<T, V> extractor; //the value extractor to get what's needed for the comparison
    private boolean boundaryHit; //the flag that keeps track of whether the boundary was hit

    public BoundedPredicate(V boundary, Function<T, V> extractor) {
        super();
        this.boundary = boundary;
        this.extractor = extractor;
    }

    public boolean test(T value) {
        //boundary was hit last time so return false now
        if( boundaryHit) {
            return false;
        }
        
        //check boundary and if it was hit, update the flag
        if( boundary.compareTo(extractor.apply(value)) <= 0) {
            boundaryHit = true;
        }
        
        return true;
    }       
}
```

And usage:

```
return StreamSupport.stream(this, true)
        .takeWhile(
           new BoundedPredicate<Solution, Integer>(problem.animals().size(), solution -> solution.pairs().size() )                
        )
        .max(Solution.byMatched)
        .get();
```

Comment: For a generic implementation that seems reasonable. Given that this will only be used in one special case I've just written a specific-purpose `private static class OneMorePredicate implements Predicate<Solution>` inner class that has the boundary and extractor hard-coded.

Comment: @Reinderien sure that's fine :)